How to filter the base table based on the values in query table while using the vector_search function in BigQuery
Sorry if the title isn't really clear, but hopefully the description will make more sense.
According to the documentation for vector_search in BigQuery, if I want to use the vector_search function, I will need two things: the base table that contains all the embedding and the query table that contains the embedding(s) I want to find the closest match for.
For example:
SELECT *
FROM
  VECTOR_SEARCH(
    (SELECT * FROM mydataset.table1 WHERE doc_id = 4),
    'my_embedding',
    (SELECT  doc_id, embedding FROM mydataset.table2),
    'embedding',
    top_k => 2,
    options => '{"use_brute_force":true}');

Where table1 is the base table and table2 is the query table.
My issue or concern I am dealing with is, so I want to filter the base table based on the corresponding doc id for each row in the query table - how do I do that.
For example - in my query table I have 3 rows:



doc id
embeddings




1
[1, 2, 3, 4]


2
[5, 5, 6, 7]


3
[9, 10, 11, 12]



I want to find the closest match for each row/embedding, but all the matches should be associated with their doc ids. It is like applying the vector_search function thrice above but instead of doc_id = 4, I am separately doing doc_id = 1, doc_id = 2, and doc_id = 3
I have thought of some approaches like:

Having a parameterized python script and sending asynchronous requests, but the issue with that approach is that I have to worry about having the right  amount of infrastructure to scale this - and, this will be outside of the bigquery eco-system

Writing a BigQuery procedure. However, BigQuery scripts will loop through the values/parameters sequentially instead of in parallel - hence making the process slower.

Do K-means on the embeddings of each document using BigQuery ML and store the centroids of the documents in separate table, and then for each document I calculate the cosine distance the between the centroids and then based on the centroids query all the values in the cluster, etc. Long story short, recreate the IVF indexing process from scratch on BigQuery at the document level.


If I can come up with a solution to modify the  vector_search function to allow filtering the base table based on the values of the query table for a corresponding row - that would save a lot of time and effort.

As far as I know you can't directly filter the base table based on the query table within the VECTOR_SEARCH function itself. The VECTOR_SEARCH function expects a static base table. It doesn't allow dynamic filtering based on the individual embeddings being queried.
What you can do is to use a JOIN function to filter the base table before applying the VECTOR_SEARCH:
SELECT t2.doc_id AS query_doc_id, nearest.* EXCEPT (embedding)
FROM mydataset.table2 AS t2
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
    VECTOR_SEARCH(
        (SELECT embedding FROM mydataset.table2 WHERE doc_id = t2.doc_id), 
        'embedding',
        (SELECT embedding FROM mydataset.table1 WHERE doc_id = t2.doc_id), 
        'embedding',
        top_k => 2,
        options => '{"use_brute_force":true}'
    )
) AS nearest;

